# Major problem with Nvidia after a release upgrade, 12.04 to 14.04. Can't access terminal to fix it!

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, upgrade, freeze

After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 I experience a complete freeze at the login.

I can't use any input devices, so I can't use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get to the command line.

I can't ssh in for whatever reason.

Recovery menu either freezes or doesn't allow any input, I cannot tell.

Anything I can do?

I need this up and running ASAP, it's an important webserver.

Comment: Did you try "nomodeset" on the grub linux line?  Did you try adding "text" to that line (not sure that's valid but...)

Comment: Okay, doing now. Will update

Comment: I have one line that reads “gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode”. Is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, ALL FIXED. I hope that anyone with this problem can see it. All I had to do was get a 12 or 14.04 live install, pick the advanced options, then go into the recovery mode. Pick drop into root shell. THEN I ran sudo dpkg --configure -a, then installed Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [little how-to](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-change-boot-runlevel-with-grub2/) to have GRUB boot your machine to single user mode (runlevel 1).

Then you should be able to access system logs to understand why your server freezes at boot.

But please tell me you still have a way to revert machine to 12.04 !